# Creating div on button click with Javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button in a webpage that is linked to a Javascript function, which creates a div as follows:

```
function creatediv(){
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('innerhtmlbox').value;
   document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

However, it is not working. Can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: what is `document.getElementById('innerhtml').value`

Comment: First I'd just put alert("hey"); to make sure your button click is actually being registered...

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/t4c5yq24/**

Comment: is document.getElementById('innerhtml') a form element? if not, the result of value seems doubtful to me.

Comment: Protip: for the sake of readability don't name your element after a DOM attribute. It can get confusing.

Comment: "is not working" is not a problem description. Please tell us what you want your code to do, and what it does instead. Have you taken a look at the console, there might be error messages waiting for you. Also, an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed, the function you've posted works as it is, when called at a correct time. We've to see the button, and how and when you're calling `createDiv`, and what is `#innerhtml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function createDiv() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = document.getElementById('getText').innerText;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="createDiv()">Click me!</button>

<div id="getText" style="display: none;">
  INNER TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that the function works, or did you actually change anything? Maybe an explanation!

Comment: This works. I may be wrong here, but I believe the `.value` function is to return the content of text fields, as in inputs, that's why I believe the code that OP was trying to execute didnt work

Comment: But how do you know the OP isn't using an input to get the HTML that is to be used in the newly created element ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `innerText`

```
function creatediv() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('innerhtml').textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
creatediv();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8jn9pj5/3/

Or if you are populating it from button's value you may use .value as suggested by `adeneo` http://jsfiddle.net/t4c5yq24/

Comment: Nope, you don't need to do that at all, `innerHTML` works just fine. Also, `innerText` is IE specific, and not cross-browser, today using `textContent` is probably a better idea, but again, it's not needed here.

Comment: Also, I dont think `innerText` is a `standard`

Comment: I agree using `textContent` is better in case it is coming from content of another div. But yes most probably he is populating it from button's value so none of it is required.